# XSL attribute without value

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I would to insert the "download" html attribuite inside an anchor element using an xsl file. The result I want to obtain is

```
<a id="custom" href="#" download class="btn btn-default btn--download">Download</a>
```

I did a lot of tries without any significant result. I tried to use xsl:attribute element without value specification but the result is not what I search for.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="download"/>
```

example you required that is not an attribute that's free text which is not allow inside the tag.

**XSLT you can use:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="a">
        <a id="custom" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn--download">
            <xsl:attribute name="download"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2K/1

Comment: Why not simply `<a id="custom" href="#" download="" class="btn btn-default btn--download">`? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2K/2

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, you're right. I was not sure that download is simpli equal to download="" but you're right. I resolved. Thanks a lot.